# Word for pattern made by curtains

Tags: word-choice

Curtains, when hung up make an "S" pattern back and forth.

I was recently talking about hanging up a sheet on a wall, and the sentence I wanted to say was similar to:

"If you hang up that sheet, then it'll be _____".

*Wrinkly* comes to mind, but that implies permanency, which is not what I want.

Is there a word that means "not flat" in a non-permanent way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curtain is ***pleated***.  The "S" pattern you described is accomplished by gathering the curtain onto a rod where the length of the curtain is longer (wider) than the rod, resulting in a soft pleating, as opposed to a sharp, or knife pleat as found on kilts and schoolgirl uniforms.

A curtain hanging on a wall, flat, would not have the same affect, but gathered on a rod attached the wall, would have the same softly pleated characteristics.

Comment: Perfect. I was actually going to attempt an answer to this question, but I couldn't possibly compete with that. Pardon my old fashioned outlook but I should have known that soft-furnishings are a lady's department.

Comment: I'll take the compliment @WS2 - I know my realms! :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Undulating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undulated) (or undulated) might suit. Derived from Latin "undula", a wavelet.

It connotes large surfaces, particularly, the sea.

Comment: Doesn't undulating imply constant motion though?

Comment: @barrycarter Apart from the sea, it is also used about sands or, in general, landscape. But you're probably right that the association with regular, ceaseless motion is somehow there (I'm not sure about "constant motion" :).

Comment: "continuous motion" is what I meant. What are the odds of finding linguistic nitpickers here? ;)